# Fulltext Index does not work properly

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

this is my first post although I read your threads on a regular base.

The problem I face has to do with the FULLTEXT index on a table of mine. You can see the procedure I followed below:

```
CREATE TABLE dost(
  author VARCHAR(30),
  title VARCHAR(40),
  isbn SMALLINT NOT NULL)ENGINE MyISAM;

ALTER TABLE dost ADD FULLTEXT(author);

ALTER TABLE dost ADD FULLTEXT(author);

ALTER TABLE dost ADD FULLTEXT(author);
```

After I inserted some data into the table, it looked something like this:

```
author                 title                               isbn

Fyodor Dostoyevsky     Poor Folk                           225125
Fyodor Dostoyevsky     Crime and Punishment                121320
Fyodor Dostoyevsky     The Gambler                         124239
Rowan Williams         Dostoyevsky                         083409
Joseph Frank           Dostoyevsky: A Writer In His Time   089823
```

The problem occurs when I try to use the MATCH AGAINST command to the author column.
To be more specific, when I type

```
SELECT author,title FROM dost WHERE MATCH(author) AGAINST('Williams');
```

I get the expected result ( Rowan Williams         Dostoyevsky ) BUT when I follow the same procedure and change the AGAINST input from 'Williams' to 'Dostoyevsky' it outputs an empty set as a result. On the other hand, the FULLTEXT index on the title column works fine. Any ideas why this problem is caused?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing what is called a *natural language* search.  In this type of search, any word that is in 50% or more of the rows will be ignored as a "common value."  [Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

If that limitation isn't what you want, then you'll need to do a [boolean full-text](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) search instead, like this:

```
SELECT author,title FROM dost WHERE MATCH(author) AGAINST('+Dostoyevsky' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: Thank you Luke! I was really struggling to understand why it was not working! So, either I do it with Boolean full-text search or by normalizing the table in order to make sure that the 'Dostoyevsky' word is in less than 50% of the rows.

Comment: @user2966210, correct.  If you don't need other benefits of the natural language searching (such as relevancy sorting) then the boolean option may be better.  Please accept this answer if it answers your question.